# Android Javascript Interface Fail

Tags: java, javascript, android

I am using Javascript Interface in my application.

When i run Debug on my device(Galaxy 3) it run perfectly without any problem,but when i make a release apk file the JavaScript is probably not running.

This is the `JavaScriptInterface` Class:

```
public class StreamingMediaPlayer{

    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
             mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void FinishExtract(String url) {

        }
   }
}
```

Now i think it's because the proguard file:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
-dontwarn com.commonsware.cwac.sacklist.**
-dontwarn com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.**
-dontwarn com.nineoldandroids.**
-dontwarn com.apps.model.**

-keep class com.millennialmedia.android.** {*;}
-keep public class cmn.Proguard$KeepMembers 
-keep public class * implements cmn.Proguard$KeepMembers
-keepclassmembers class * implements cmn.Proguard$KeepMembers { 
   <methods>; 
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface

-keep class com.apps.model.** { *; } 
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Did i need to add something to the `proguard` File? Did the problem can be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that proguard obfuscates the FinishExtract method. 
Then the javascript can't find it because it assumes the name is still "FinishExtract"

To fix it you can change your code to:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface  implements cmn.Proguard.KeepMembers {
```

Your proguard config specifies that classes which implement KeepMembers should stay unobfuscated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to add the StreamingMediaPlayer class to the proguard file? Also might want to un-comment the config for webview, as per the instructions in the comment in the proguard file

Comment: Yes adding the StreamingMediaPlayer.JavaScriptInterface to proguard config would fix it too.  I prefer the solution with the interface since you only need to add this once and can use it in many places (eg for several javascript interface classes) without keeping the classnames in sync with the proguard config.